# Xamarin.Forms Styles preview colors are not showing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In which case, the color preview of a DynamicResource does not appear?

I was expecting this:
[With style color preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcdbz.png)

The above is from another sample project with a behavior I'm trying to reproduce.

Instead, I have something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp5Nh.png)

SimpleEmailEntry.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.LoginForms.SimpleEmailEntry"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:border="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Border;assembly=Syncfusion.Core.XForms"
    xmlns:control="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:StringToBooleanConverter x:Key="StringToBooleanConverter" />
            <converter:ErrorValidationColorConverter x:Key="ErrorValidationColorConverter" PageVariantParameter="1" />
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <border:SfBorder
                BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Gray-White}"
                BorderColor="{Binding Path=IsFocused, Source={x:Reference EmailEntry}, Converter={x:StaticResource ErrorValidationColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference EmailEntry}}"
                Style="{StaticResource SfBorderStyle}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <control:BorderlessEntry
                        x:Name="EmailEntry"
                        Placeholder="Email" Keyboard="Email"
                        PlaceholderColor="{DynamicResource Gray-700}"
                        Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"
                        Text="{Binding Email}"
                        TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray-900}" />
                    

                    <Label
                        Margin="15,0"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource FontIcons}"
                        FontSize="18"
                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                        IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Source={x:Reference ValidationLabel}}"
                        Text="&#xe707;"
                        TextColor="{DynamicResource Red}"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />


                </Grid>
            </border:SfBorder>

            <Label
                x:Name="ValidationLabel"
                Margin="15,-5,0,0"
                FontSize="12"
                IsVisible="{Binding Path=IsFocused, Source={x:Reference EmailEntry}, Converter={StaticResource StringToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference EmailEntry}}"
                Text="Please enter the valid e-mail"
                TextColor="{DynamicResource Red}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             x:Class="MyApp.App"
             xmlns:themes = "clr-namespace:MyApp.Themes;assembly=MyApp">

    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <themes:LightTheme />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

LightTheme.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="MyApp.Themes.LightTheme"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#f54e5e</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryDarkColor">#d0424f</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryDarkenColor">#ab3641</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryLighterColor">#edcacd</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryGradient">#e83f94</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryLight">#ffe8f4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SecondaryGradient">#7644ad</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Secondary">#d54381</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Green">#7ed321</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Red">#ff4a4a</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Orange">#ff844a</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Blue">#4acaff</Color>
    <Color x:Key="HyperLink">#567cd7</Color>

    <Color x:Key="Gray-100">#f6f7f8</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray-200">#ebecef</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray-300">#ced2d9</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray-400">#b2b8c2</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray-500">#959eac</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray-600">#788396</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray-700">#606a7b</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray-800">#4a515e</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray-900">#333942</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray-Black">#000000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Gray-White">#ffffff</Color>

    <OnPlatform x:Key="FontIcons" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <OnPlatform.Platforms>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="UIFontIcons.ttf#UIFontIcons" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="UIFontIcons" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/UIFontIcons.ttf#UIFontIcons" />
        </OnPlatform.Platforms>
    </OnPlatform>

    <OnPlatform x:Key="Montserrat-SemiBold" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <OnPlatform.Platforms>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf#Montserrat-SemiBold" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-SemiBold" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf#Montserrat-SemiBold" />
        </OnPlatform.Platforms>
    </OnPlatform>

    <OnPlatform x:Key="Montserrat-Regular" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <OnPlatform.Platforms>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Regular" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Montserrat-Regular.ttf#Montserrat-Regular" />
        </OnPlatform.Platforms>
    </OnPlatform>

    <OnPlatform x:Key="Montserrat-Medium" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <OnPlatform.Platforms>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Medium.ttf#Montserrat-Medium" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Medium" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Montserrat-Medium.ttf#Montserrat-Medium" />
        </OnPlatform.Platforms>
    </OnPlatform>

    <OnPlatform x:Key="Montserrat-Bold" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <OnPlatform.Platforms>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Montserrat-Bold.ttf#Montserrat-Bold" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Montserrat-Bold" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Montserrat-Bold.ttf#Montserrat-Bold" />
        </OnPlatform.Platforms>
    </OnPlatform>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the wrong way for resource dictionaries. Check the steps below.

1. Create the `LightTheme.xaml` in your project.
2. Assume that the `LightTheme.xaml` is in the same assembly. If you want to use the resource dictionaries from other assemblies, you could add it into the MergedDictionaries property of the ResourceDictionary. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#merge-resource-dictionaries-from-other-assemblies

   Set the resource dictionaries in `SimpleEmailEntry.xaml`:

   ```
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="ResourceDictionaryDemo.HomePage">

     <ResourceDictionary>           
        <ResourceDictionary Source="LightTheme.xaml" />          
    </ResourceDictionary>

   </ContentPage>
   ```
3. Use the color with key.

   ```
   <Label
        BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Key=Gray-Black}"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Text="ListView with a DataTemplateSelector" />
   ```